# how to set key font size in gnuplot?

Tags: gnu, gnuplot

How to `set key`(legend) **font size** in gnuplot?

I read the gnuplot introduction file and find no related configuration about this property. I can set font type and size for labels, tics, but only key can not be set the font?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The font for the key can be set in gnuplot 4.4. For example:

```
set key font ",20"
```

would set the size of the font to 20.

Comment: So, there's no way to do it with older versions of gnuplot? e.g. 4.2

Answer (score 6):

For older gnuplot versions like 4.2, you can do:

```
set terminal enhanced font "Helvetica,18"
```

It will apply to any textual labels in the terminal.

Comment: How about terminal epslatex in older version. Is there a way to set the font?

Answer (score 0):

You can also set and unset key font depending on your needs, for example, I needed a title and label bigger than the sizes of the tag labels inside the plot:

```
set terminal svg size 300, 480\
set termoption enhanced\
set key font "Times New Roman, 18"\
....\
unset key\
set key font "Times New Roman, 14"\
plot ''  ... title "Cd-4d". **<--**  This is smaller than the other labels
```